# Set active a disabled tab panel in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have 3 tab panels which have forms in it. The first tab is visible to the user, upon clicking on a save button the other two tabs which are initially disabled, becomes enabled for the user. Now what i'm trying to do, since each tab has a save button,is the following:
initial case: 
tab 1:enabled
tab 2: disabled
tab 3: disabled
upon clicking save in tab 1, only tab 2 is enabled. And upon clicking the save button in tab 2, tab 3 is enabled.

This my current code which opens tab 2 and 3 on clicking save in tab 1.

```
for (var i = 1; i < tabPanel.items.length; i++) {
           tabPanel.items.get(i).setDisabled(false);
    }
    tabPanel.setActiveTab(2);
    tabPanel.setActiveTab(1);
```

How can i edit my code to get the desired case?

Comment: Can you show the html? Or at least how the buttons are structured?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one Savebutton in all the three tabs, it would be sth. like

```
var activeTab = tabPanel.getActiveTab(),
    sibling = activeTab.nextSibling();
if(sibling) tabPanel.setActiveTab(sibling);
activeTab.disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a tab status array depends on which save button was clicked.

```
var tabStatus = [true, false, false],
    tabStatus2 = [false, true, false],
    tabStatus3 = [false, true, true];

for (var i = 0; i < tabPanel.items.length; i++) {
   tabPanel.items.get(i).setDisabled(tabStatus1[i]);
}
```